# call codeigniter API from outside the framework

Tags: codeigniter

I have an iPhone application which perform calls to an API developed with codeigniter. Since I am new to the framework, I want to know where such API are normally located ? The url requested from the iPhone application to the API is the following:

http://example.com/site/welcome/admin/api/processingdocuments/

I got a look on the `application/libraries` folder and there is a bench of php files like `rest.php` and `REST_Controller.php`. Are these the files I am looking for? Since the URL above doesn't point to specific file, how to know which API is being called? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

When using [Phil Sturgeon's CodeIgniter Restserver](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) (which is what it seems you are using), you set up a controller within `application/controllers` directory and extend his class.

Let's say you call your controller `Foobar`, and it looks like this:

```
class Foobar extends Rest_Controller {

  //... your methods here

}
```

In this case, you will access this endpoint at `http://example.com/foobar`

---

The URL references your controllers, and not the Rest_Controller directly.

URLs look like this:

```
http://example.com/{controller}/{method}/{param1}/{param2}/.../{paramN}
```

If method is not specified, it defaults to `index()`

---

Further, the Restserver allows you to map methods to HTTP request methods. Such that

GET example.com/foobar will map to the method `index_get()`
POST example.com/foobar will map to the method `index_post()`
..and so on.

I highly recommend you read the [documentation](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver)

---

In your example, you would expect the controller that is being called to be located at `application/controllers/site`.

However, this might have been modified using htaccess rewrite rules (check for a `.htaccess` file), or via redefined CI routes (check `application/config/routes.php`).

---

If all else fails:

Under default configurations, that is where you should find them, however, CI is very malleable with routes and it is hard to say where they might be. Your best bet would be to grep the directory for the words `extends Rest_Controller` since wherever the controllers are, they would be extending that class.

Comment: Hi, Thanx for this detailed answer. Some notes though, why I don't get some controllers files under application/controllers folder? there is only `index.php file right there.